# Videomapping tutorials

Tags: video

Anybody knows how or where I can see tutorials about Videomapping? I searched a lot. Truthly, I found lots of info about Madmapper, Modul8, etc..., but I am looking for something fully awesoe, like real practical examples, how I build the scaled video and how I can play all that stuff (more than a simple loop) into projection.
Thanks to all.

Comment: I hope someone has a good answer.  I personally hadn't even heard of the term until you mentioned it.  My guess is there probably isn't a whole lot out there about it since it is pretty rarely seen or used from what I can gather about it.  I'll do some more research later and see if I can find anything though.  It sounds interesting.

Comment: Hi AJ. You did not know what VM is? Yeah, I strongly believe that it is an unknown concept in lot of countries, here in Portugal is growing...
So check this out: ["Full Tutorial"](http://www.weltlighting.com/blogs/3d-video-mapping-projection-tutorial/), I seriously hope that this fast tutorial helps you like helped me. :)